# Since IPSec works on Layer 3 (Network), does that mean it also provides protection for all the higher layers?

Tags: ipsec

From my understanding, data moves from OSI Layer 7 down to Layer 1 when its being prepared to get sent. On each layer, data gets encapsulated within the data of the layer below it. Ex: A Layer 3 IP packet is encapsulated within a Layer 2 ethernet frame.

So does that mean IPSec provides protection for all the higher layers since Layer 7 - Layer 4 data are all encapsulated within a Layer 3 packet?

Answer (score 2):

IPSec protects the data layer 4 and up (TCP ...) in transport mode or even layer 3 and up (IP ...) in tunnel mode - see [Modes of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec#Modes_of_operation). This therefore includes also the application data.

Comment: Yep. For example, a lot of VPNs use IPSec for securing the traffic between VPN client and server, and no other cryptography is needed (once the client and server are authenticated and the tunnel securely established) to protect the tunneled traffic. Of course, in practice you may want TLS anyhow for when the traffic _exits_ the IPSec tunnel or transport, if it gets forwarded on further (as in a VPN).